# Parts Per Million

Tags: stoichiometry, alcohols

I am trying to calculate how many milliliters of a solution I cannot exceed to create $\pu{200ppm}$ in the air of isopropyl alcohol. The $\pu{26ml}$ bottle of solution is 70% isopropyl alcohol. Using the density ($\pu{0.786 g/ml}$) and molar mass ($\pu{60.10g/mol}$), I calculate a total of $\pu{0.24 mol}$ of isopropyl alcohol in $\pu{26ml}$ bottle of solution.

Now, I use the ideal gas law to determine the number of moles in the room. Using $\pu{P= 30 inHg}$, $\pu{V= 68.94m3}$, $\pu{T= 18.33°C}$, I get a number of moles of air in the room at $\pu{2889.79 mol}$.

First, am I doing the calculations right and second, where do I go from here? I am not factoring in A/C units, people walking in the room, or anything to change the air in the room.

Comment: I think you made an arithmetic error or typo on the moles of IPA you have in the question, I got .34 moles. Remember that "ppm" stands for parts per million, you can figure out the ppm level you have once you have the amount of IPA and amount of air in the desired units.

Comment: Here is my train of thought: 26ml x .7= 18.2. I am using the p=m/v where p is .786 (density), mass is unknown and v is 18.2. Once you work out the math, you have mass as 14.30 grams. Then, I am using molar mass (60.10 grams/mole) and canceling out grams to get .23 moles of isopropyl alcohol in 26ml of solution.

Comment: I whiffed that one, I skipped over the "70% IPA" in your description. So you have the right number of mols. Now that you have mols of IPA and mols of air molecules, you can setup the ratio and figure out what ppm of IPA you will have in the air (in terms of mols). Depending on how accurate you want this, you will need to find other ways to quantify the amount of air you have in the room. If you can work in terms of volumes, you can just use the room volume; if you can work in terms of mass, you can find charts for air density as a function of temperature.

Comment: Welcome to Chem SE! Take a [tour] of our site, and visit the [help] to learn how this site works. Good luck.